# How do I dynamically add a class to a dynamically printed ol based on a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, html

this is an example script from “PHP Advanced and Object-Oriented Programming: Visual QuickPro Guide (3rd Edition)” by Larry Ullman.

The question I have is how could I dynamically add an html class depending on how nested each item is. For example I'd like to add a class task to all parent tasks, a class subtask to all subtasks, a class subsubtask to all subtasks of subtasks, and I would like to it dynamically no matter how nested an item might be. I am open to any approaches of dealing with such a problem and this particular example is just a reference as I understand there might be a much better way to go about this, including changes to what information is stored in the arrays. I would just like to know a general approach to dealing with printing multidimensional arrays in an ol and adding a class that dynamically indicates how nested each item is, so that I may then style them independently. Any help is really appreciated, I'm still learning everyday.

[FullScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkEAu.png)

[curarrayandoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1mwk.png)

```
    <?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$tasks = array(
    0 => array(
        1 => 'Task 1',
        2 => 'Task 2',
        3 => 'Task 3',
        8 => 'Task 4',
    ),
    2 => array(
        4 => 'Subtask 1',
        5 => 'Subtask 2',
        6 => 'Subtask 3',
    ),
    5 => array(
        7 => 'Subsubtask 1',
    ),
);

echo '<ol>';
printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasks[0]);
echo '</ol>';

function printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasksToBePrinted, $level = 0)
{

        echo '<ol class="';
        if($level > 0) {
            echo str_repeat('sub', $level);
            }
        echo 'task">';

       foreach ($tasksToBePrinted as $id => $taskName) {
         echo '<li>' . $taskName . '</li>';

       if (isset($tasks[$id])) {
            printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasks[$id], $level + 1);
        }

        }

       echo '</ol>';


}





 <ol><ol class="task">
<li>Task 1</li>
<li>Task 2</li>
<ol class="subtask">
<li>Subtask 1</li>
<li>Subtask 2</li>
<ol class="subsubtask">
<li>Subsubtask 1</li>
</ol>
<li>Subtask 3</li>
</ol>
<li>Task 3</li>
<li>Task 4</li>
</ol></ol>
```

Comment: what do u want PHP or HTML class ? I am kinda misunderstand.

Comment: As this is your 1st question on SO, here are some tips to make your question better. (1) don't give us your code as an image. the image of your desired output is fine, but code should always be directly added. (2) you need to show some effort. even if it is just showing the actual html source code you want as a result. Currently this question is way too broad for SO as it appears to give the message of "give me the code", even if that is not your intent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Sean! Yeah I'm going to get better at asking questions, up until now all my questions had already been asked so I never needed to ask one. This is a really great community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
$tasks = array(
    0 => array(
        1 => 'Task 1',
        2 => 'Task 2',
        3 => 'Task 3',
        8 => 'Task 4',
    ),
    2 => array(
        4 => 'Subtask 1',
        5 => 'Subtask 2',
        6 => 'Subtask 3',
    ),
    5 => array(
        7 => 'Subsubtask 1',
    ),
);

printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasks[0]);

function printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasksToBePrinted, $level = 0)
{
    echo '<ol' . ($level > 0 ? ' class="' . str_repeat('sub', $level) . 'task"' : '') . '>';

    foreach ($tasksToBePrinted as $id => $taskName) {
        echo "<li>$taskName</li>";

        if (isset($tasks[$id])) {
            printTasksRecursively($tasks, $tasks[$id], $level + 1);
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

The output would be:

```
<ol>
    <li>Task 1</li>
    <li>Task 2</li>
    <ol class="subtask">
        <li>Subtask 1</li>
        <li>Subtask 2</li>
        <ol class="subsubtask">
            <li>Subsubtask 1</li>
        </ol>
        <li>Subtask 3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Task 3</li>
    <li>Task 4</li>
 </ol>
```

Comment: I don't understand which is the difference.. can you please explain more.. you want the subtasks in other `ol` element?

Comment: Yes I will explain in a moment. Sorry I had to work suddenly, I teach classes online and a student just showed up. I will finish work in one hour and then explain, although I think I know how to do it now, you can tell me if I'm right. Sorry about being unclear this is my first time asking my own question on here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited my question to include the solution you helped me to reach. Thanks again!

Comment: @LucasCoder I just updated my answer to print what you need..